# How to remove y axis restrain in lattice?

Tags: r, lattice

I would like to remove y axis restrain in my xyplot plot using lattice in R.

Here is my code:

```
  Annual.Average=equal.count(coredata(ScottsCk_AMC[1743:3569,"365ma"]),4,1/2);
  Seasonal.Average=equal.count(coredata(ScottsCk_AMC[1743:3569,"90ma"]),4,1/2)

  xyplot(coredata(ScottsCk_AMC[1743:3569,"original"])~coredata(ScottsCk_AMC[1743:3569,"1lag"])|Annual.Average*Seasonal.Average,aspect=1,
    prepanel = function(x, y) 
        prepanel.loess(x, y, span = 1),
        panel = function(x, y){
        panel.grid(h = 2, v = 2)
        panel.xyplot(x, y, cex = .5)
        panel.loess(x, y, span = 1,col="red",lwd=2)},
        xlab = "Rainfall on Precedding day",ylab = "Runoff Coefficients (Flow / Rain)")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the argument of `scales = list(y = list(relation = "free"))`.